# Porting from itextsharp to to itext 7 - how to get the font weight of text from a PDF document?

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am porting my code from **itextsharp** to **itext7** and facing difficulties with font weight. Here is a snippet of my code from **itextsharp** (not the best code!) but worked well and gave me the font weight wherever available.

```
    public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy :    LocationTextExtractionStrategy
    {

        public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
        var oFont = renderInfo.GetFont();
        var fieldFontWeight = oFont.GetType().BaseType.GetField(
                           "fontWeight",                                           
                           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField | 
                           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        System.Single fontWeight = (System.Single)fieldFontWeight.
                            GetValue(oFont);
        }    
    }
```

I am unable to get the equivalent of the above using **itext 7**.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Sau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find an explicit `fontWeight` member like there was in iText 5, either, but nothing can keep us from looking into the **FontDescriptor** ourselves, e.g. like this:

```
public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    public override void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (data is TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            var oFont = renderInfo.GetFont();
            PdfDictionary fontDescriptor = oFont.GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.FontDescriptor);
            PdfNumber number = fontDescriptor?.GetAsNumber(PdfName.FontWeight);
            double? weight = number?.GetValue();
            [... process weight, it is null if not set in the descriptor ...]
        }
        base.EventOccurred(data, type);
    }
}
```